# Is there any genealogy software that will assemble lists of cousins from a gedcom?

Tags: software-recommendations

Are there software programs that will compile lists of cousins at each degree (2nd, 3rd, 4th etc) of a target (or "home") person from a gedcom?

Viz: Among the 6000 persons in my gedcom, what are the names of my 4th cousins.

Answer (score 2):

Family Historian does some of this on an individual by individual basis when you look at an individuals record in relation to the root person. If you wanted a list of names and their relationships this would be possible with a custom query in Family Historian, they are easy to write using the inbuilt query function. You can try the free trial version available from them to check it out. Their website is [here](https://www.family-historian.co.uk/).

Answer (score 2):

Brother's Keeper has a report called "All Relatives of a Person". If I limit it to 6 generations, and exclude spouses and deceased people, it gives me 23 pages with relationships. You can easily spot the clusters of 3rd, 4th cousins, etc. (Without limitations, I get about 300 pages.)